# Best ways to manipulate getfacl output?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/313409/howto-prevent-chrgrp-from-clearing-setuid-bit) I figured that using "chgrp -R" resets the setuid bits on my binaries; which causes quite some grieve for our application.

Still, I have to run two commands to ensure that all things belong to a certain user; and that all things have "g+w" on them.

I think "most controlled" way of getting to that:

1. Run getfacl and create a "textual snapshot" of the current settings
2. Rework that file
3. Apply with setfacl

So, I need to process a file like this:

Lines with

```
# group: root
```

should turn into

```
# group: whatever
```

and lines like

```
group::?-?
```

should become

```
group::?w?
```

Preserving the actual 'wildcard' content: what I mean is: I only want to "enable" w; and I dont want to change anything else on that line.

Example:

```
group::r--
```

gets

```
group::rw-
```

and

```
group::--x
```

becomes

```
group::-wx
```

Now I need to turn that into some bash/sed/awk thing. Can somebody help?

( I already figured the first part

```
sed s/'^# group: root'/'#group: nobody'/g
```

but struggling with the rest)

Comment: Can you be more specific? For example, do you always need to convert `?-?` into `?w?` ?

Comment: See my updates.

Comment: `group::?-?` doesn't start with a `#` ?

Comment: @Inian These are two different informations: "#group:" gives the name of the *owning* group; whereas "group::" gives the group permissions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sed` similarly to the following examples:

```
echo 'group::?-?' | sed 's/\(^group::.\).\(.\)/\1w\2/'  # gives  group::?w?

echo '#group:root' | sed 's/\(^#group:\).*/\1whatever/' # gives  #group:whatever
```

Answer (score 2):

I have put together a not-so-straight forward `awk` logic, but it works the same for all your cases.

```
awk -F"[:]+" -vOFS="::" '{if ($2 == ": root") $2=" whatever"; if (substr($2,2,1) == "-") $2=substr($2,1,1)"w"substr($2,3)}1' file
```

For an input file

```
# group: root
group::?-?
group::--x
group::y--
```

The command produces output as

```
$ awk -F"[:]+" -vOFS="::" '{if ($2 == ": root") $2=" whatever"; if (substr($2,2,1) == "-") $2=substr($2,1,1)"w"substr($2,3)}1' file
# group: whatever
group::?w?
group::-wx
group::yw-
```

Few useful notes:-

- `-F"[:]+"` is for one or more instances of the de-limiter `:` to work with and `-vOFS="::"` for output field separation.
- The condition `if (substr($2,2,1) == "-") $2=substr($2,1,1)"w"substr($2,3)` is nothing but if the middle character contains `-` replace it with `w`. Please note, this will not work when the `xxx` part in `group::xxx` contains more than 3 characters.